# sorting links on multiple criteria

Tags: sorting

So I'm sure someone has already done something similar. I've got a custom list of links, and track how many times they were clicked, and when last they were clicked. I want to sort them somehow usefully based upon both factors. Anyone can point me towards an existing solution or better yet discussion thereof? I have a few ideas of how this could be implemented, but expect there is an easier answer.
EDITED FOR CLARIFICATION (was using phone to post):

So my current idea is to halve the weight of the clicks, double each period, with a period being a day. That is:

`Day ...  # Clicks are

<1 .....  Full Value

<2 .....  Halved value

<4 .....  1/4th value

<8 .....  1/8th value`

The premise being that both recency and frequency of clicks means it would be more useful to have them first in the list.

Comment: It might help if you gave us some idea about the language you want to do this in. Do you want to just sort them by one criteria or the other or do you want some form of weighted sort that combines the two but not as simple as just adding the two scores?

Comment: Are you asking for an *implementation* (which is trivial once you have a total order), or are you asking us to come up with an ordering for you?

Comment: What technology do you use? How do you store information about cliks? Can you describe your problem with more details?

Comment: @Amos: I'll probably be implementing it w/ PHP but really I'm more interested in the theory behind it which should be moderatly code agnostic.
@Anon.: I'm not positive what you mean. It is very easy to find different sorting algorithems based on a single variable, but I'm not really sure where to start for sorting on multiple criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the simplest way is just a weighted mean of both values, you should first normalize them according to their max value like

- find max number of clicks between all links
- calculate a normalized clicks value as `clicks / maxClicks`, this will span from 0.0 to 1.0
- choose a max threshold of oldness of your links (for example 4 months)
- calculate a normalized 'freshness' value as `(now - lastVisited) / threshold`, discarding all items that had been clicked before your threshold
- calculate a weighted mean as normalizedClickValue * alpha + normalizedFreshness * (1.0 - alpha)

You can start from something like this and then tweak it according to your needs..

Comment: What is "alpha" here? This is definitely the type of thing suggestion I was looking for!

Comment: It's a factor that you choose in range (0.0, 1.0) to express how much weight you want to do to first of two factors involved in the average